# How can I parse javascript in c# to separate a code file?

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net

Here's an example script file that I want to parse:

```
<script>
  module.exports = function() {
    internals: function() {
      return {
        key: "value",
        anotherKey: "some other value"
      }
    },

    fruit: {
      apples: function() {
        return "Don't like them";
      },
      bananas: function() {
        return "Yuck";
      } 
    },

    drinks: {
      water: function(ice) {
        return ice ? "water with ice" : "just water";
      }
    }
  }
</script>
```

What I'd like is the following:

```
List<string, string> internals;
List<string, string> fruit;
List<string, string> drinks;
```

So that `internals` would contain:

```
Key: "key" Value: "value"
Key: "anotherKey" Value: "some other value"
```

And `fruit` would contain:

```
Key: "apples" Value: "function() {\n return "Don't like them"; \n}
Key: "bananas" Value: "function() {\n return "Yuck"; \n}
```

And so on...

But be able to still parse:

```
water(ice) {
  return ice ? "water with ice" : "just water";
}
```

I basically want to abstract all of the internals, fruit, and drinks so that I can iterate over them, and write then back to a file... so I may do something like:

```
foreach(var f in fruit) {
  // etc.
}
```

So that I can literally re-create the script file the way it was.

I'd love to be able to parse it regardless of arrow functions and newer `js` syntax. I just want the guts of each section. Hope this makes sense.

Comment: Doing this your self is mine-field. I have you looked at pre-built parsers ?

Comment: I have. most of them are about executing the actual code... javascript.net etc.